# jQuery: How to fire event when an element is empty or when element has children

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I write a jQuery script that will keep an eye on an element's children.

If the element has no children => scrolling for the whole page is enabled (as default)
If the element has children => scrolling for the whole page is disabled

Scrolling actions are:

```
Deactivate scrolling: jQuery("body").mousewheel(function(event,data){event.preventDefault();return false;});
Activate scrolling:   jQuery("body").unbind("mousewheel");
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: i don't think there is a function or an event *mousewheel* which you can simply unbind. Where did you find it..? are you using any plugins?? By the way, are you sure whatever you're making won't be viewd in touch devices??

Comment: Also, if you unbind an event handler, it doesn't mean that the user won't be able to perform that action again. You need to have a handler which prevents the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.setInterval("javascript function", milliseconds)` function. Have in mind that the second parameter is the interval in miliseconds. In the example the interval is 1000 miliseconds = 1 second

```
var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
   //check for children here
}, 1000)
```

You can get more information about the timing events in java script here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp